# From scratch Transformer chatbot in Pytorch poor results during testing

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, google-colaboratory, chatbot

I was using this [model](https://github.com/fawazsammani/chatbot-transformer/blob/master/transformer%20chatbot.ipynb) as inspiration but i ran into errors when preparing the dataset.Here is my colab [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11lMSvZuBL3V6npghShItVowO1jjAZt0r#scrollTo=FLh-5_xnurHg).If you want to take a look at it.The model trains and evals as expected but during testing,the model is giving bad results.It repeats the same word upto the  token.

I tried using different datasets but it didn't work.Am a begginer in this maybe its something am missing or doing wrong.i would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.